# Taking the limit of voltage division equation

Tags: voltage-divider, math

I'm required to take the limit of the voltage division equation(internal voltmeter resistance included as Rm) when Rm goes to infinity to show that the limit equals to the basic voltage division equation.

\$\varinjlim_{R_m\rightarrow\infty}\ \dfrac{R_1V_s}{R_1+R_2+R_m}\$

But I'm kind of confused.

So how should I do it?

Comment: This is more of a maths question .. also, as written, with Rm on the bottom only, it tends to zero?

Comment: Maybe Rm is meant to be "in parallel" with R1 - that would make sense. Then the limit will be R1/(R1+R2). Please check how you've written the formula

Comment: @pjc50 : That's what I found at first as well since my initial approach was wrong

Comment: I've down-voted the question because it didn't show any research effort - easy research really - just read the comment i made above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Andy aka points out, it's not entirely clear what you're asking. A schematic would help in the future. I think your original equation is incorrect. It sounds like you have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTIunn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From the basic voltage divider equation:
$$
V_{out}=\frac{R_LV_s}{R_L+R_2}
$$

Where RL is R1 || RM.

$$
R_L=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_M}}
$$

Showing that RL -> R1 as RM -> infinity is simple algebra from this point.

Now, as a matter of reality, RM is not infinite. This approximation only holds value if RM is much larger than R1. If RM is within, say, two orders of magnitude of the value of R1, the meter can affect the circuit it's attached to.

Comment: @Can - why did you dismiss what I said (2nd comment on your original question)?

Comment: @Remiel - were you unable to read my comment on Can's original question?

Comment: @Andyaka I don't disagree with your comment. The question itself is poorly phrased. But the answer, and further the fundamental concept, are still valuable.

Comment: @Remiel - would it be courtious to add to your answer that you had (or had not) seen my comment before writing your answer?

Comment: @Andyaka Sure, if you like.

Comment: @Remiel - LOL the question was for you to ponder. I've made my point and you have listened. That is good enough for me. As for what other folk may think, that is not for me to say!!!